# Basic Neural network time series models

Tags: neural-networks, gaussian-process

Suppose we have a time series of the following form:
$$\vec{R}_n = \vec{\mu}_n(\vec{\theta})+\sqrt{\Sigma_n(\vec{\theta})}\vec{Z}_n$$
Where $Z$ is a iid standard multivariate normal. We assume the mean and covariance are [predictable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predictable_process) (some authors like D. Williams say previsible), i.e. known at time $n-1$:
$$\mu_n, \Sigma_n \in \mathcal{F}_{n-1}$$ where $\mathcal{F}_n=\sigma(\vec{R}_1, \dotsc, \vec{R}_n)$. Specifically, we allow them to be functions of the $n-1$ previous observations of $R$. Here $\sigma(X)$ is the [sigma-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra) of the RV $X$ and $\mathcal{F}_n$ is the filtration of the $n$ observed random variables that are relevant, while $\Sigma$ is a covariance matrix (or rather a positive definite matrix), with, say, Cholesky decomposition $\sqrt{\Sigma}$.

Suppose further that, in some (perhaps loose) sense these coefficients are given by neural networks with parameters $\theta$ (either as the output or hidden states—I believe the latter is more appropriate if not mistaken).

**Question**
Have such models been studied and if so what are they called and what is the most accessible literature for such models?

Personally, at first I started studying recurrent neural networks since those can handle sequential data, but most literature I found is devoted to text or natural language processing applications. Then I came across neural network Gaussian processes which sounds exactly what I’m after but I am still digging through the literature. I figured I would ask here since someone might know succinctly what to look for. I could very well try to implement this myself with specified layers, parameters, the log-likelihood, and attempting backpropagation myself, but it would be more efficient to do this in e.g. pytorch, since I’m sure this idea has already been explored. Apologize if this is well known or too broad. Essentially I am looking for neural network generalizations of classic time series models (AR, GARCH). Any classic references would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: you have to explain some notation, e.g. $\sigma,\sqrt\Sigma_n$...

Comment: @utobi I added some edits. Sorry about that. I come from a probability background so sigma algebras are very common that I must’ve forgot to explain.

Comment: If we allow them to be functions of the n−1 previous observations of R, then AR is a good example but GARCH is probably not. I think ARCH would be a better match. Regardless, that does not help me answer your question...

Comment: "neural network generalizations of classic time series models" - you could put a neural network instead of the ARMA structure like this: $y_{t+1} = \mathrm{ANN}(y_{t}, y_{t-1}, y_{t-2}, \dots, y_{t-p})$, whereas in ARMA you'd have a linear function instead of the ANN. However, I can't remember any papers that did this and analyzed the results or implications of using an ANN like this.

Comment: @ForceBru Looks like I got some work cut out for myself then. Thanks for the comment.